# Don't insert on array unless nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to find and record, is the record is nil, I don't want it on my array like this:

```
@kid <<  Kid.find_only_kid(k) unless nil
```

But when I get a nil, the record is inserted on the array.

This is the code of my find_only_kid method on my model:

```
  def self.find_only_kid(kid)
    Kid.where(_id: kid.to_s, parent: false, teacher: false).first rescue nil
  end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code should be :

```
kid = Kid.find_only_kid(k)
@kid << kid unless kid.nil?
```

Note:

When a variable name is meant to hold collections, and it should be `kids` instead of `kid`. And the method name should be `find_only_kids` instead of `find_only_kid`.

Comment: `@kid << kid if kid.present?` will be more readable if you are using rails.

Comment: @SamKahChiin yeah.

Comment: Is there a one liner for this without assigning and extra variable? Something like `@kid &<< Kid.find_only_kid(k)`.